# how to use stasm library functions in python?

Tags: python, expression, face, stasm

[error what i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5psy.png).I am working on a project to recognize the facial expression using python.I am trying to use stasm library functions to find facial landmarks in my python module but that functions are not available. Please help where I'm wrong.
Thanks the library is imported in the python module then also I'm not able to use functions of stasm
 [image: 1]

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: i have mentioned a link to error check it

Comment: what is the version of openCV?

Comment: what is the stasm version?

Comment: stasm verison is stasm3.1 and opencv is 2.4.13

Comment: @Codesingh what is the issue can u please see that

Comment: sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the issue in line no. 13 it should be `stasm_search_single` not `stasm.search_single` and in line no. 18 it should be `stasm_force` not `stasm.force`

Cheers.

Comment: thnx @codesingh but that didn't worked out for me. As in python the syntax is like this only.